# Over bad box or Extra alignment tab error

Tags: equations, amsmath, split

I'm trying to place a too large equation on my article, but having 2 differents error / bad boxes when trying solve 1 of them. 
Here my whole preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}          
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}     
\usepackage{wrapfig}                        
\usepackage{mathpazo}                       
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}      
\usepackage{scrextend}                      
\usepackage{enumitem}                       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linespread{1.05}                           
\makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\@listI}{\itemsep=0pt} 
\newif\if@fleqn

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    AP_{R\$(1j)} =  \bigl[ {SIUP_{br(11)}}\times{P_{c(11)}} \ \ \ & {SIUP_{br(12)}}\times{P_{c(12)}} \ \ \ ... & \ \ \ {SIUP_{br(1(j-1))}}\times{P_{c(1(j-1))}} \ \ \ {SIUP_{br(1j)}}\times{P_{c(1j)}} 
    \bigr]  
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This one with 2 "&" generates a "Extra aligment tab has been changed to \cr" but equation looks perfect on PDF

Removing 1 of "&" i don't have this error, but have an "over" bad box and equation didnt split going out of margins

**## Edit**
Result when using 2 & in code. (but t generate error in texnic)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please, merge your code snippets into one, small and complete document  which we can copy and test in our computers.

Comment: how many lines should have your equation? one? four?

Comment: Ok Zarko, Here we go. 
Equation will be broken in 2 lines

Comment: similar to this: `\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
AP_{R\$(1j)} & = \bigl[{SIUP_{br(11)}}\times{P_{c(11)}}
              {SIUP_{br(12)}}\times{P_{c(12)}} \dots \\  ...
            & {SIUP_{br(1(j-1))}}\times{P_{c(1(j-1))}}
              {SIUP_{br(1j)}}\times{P_{c(1j)}}
                \bigr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}`?  I have filling that something is missing in your equation or it  present a vector?

Comment: ** Yes mate, it solved. I just have to adjust spacement. 
Reading amsath docs not i can understand what they say about placing "&"

Thank you very much

Comment: see my answer below. i suggest to use `multlined` instead of `split` and also show correct use of `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect, that you like to have something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[0.8\linewidth]
AP_{R\$(1j)} = \bigl[\mathit{SIUP}_{br(11)}\times P_{c(11)}\ 
                     \mathit{{SIUP}_{br(12)}\times P_{c(12)}} \dotsm \\[3pt]  
              \dotsm \mathit{SIUP}_{br(1(j-1))}\times P_{c(1(j-1))}\ 
                     \mathit{SIUP}_{br(1j)}\times P_{c(1j)}
               \bigr]
\end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As you see, in this solution I use `multlined` environment from `mathtools`. Your use of `split` environment was wrong. Ampersant in it are for anchoring split parts but you never determine them with `\\`. Solution with split can be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
AP_{R\$(1j)} = \bigl[ &
                     \mathit{SIUP}_{br(11)}\times P_{c(11)}\ 
                     \mathit{{SIUP}_{br(12)}\times P_{c(12)}} \dotsm \\[3pt]
                      &  
              \dotsm \mathit{SIUP}_{br(1(j-1))}\times P_{c(1(j-1))}\ 
                     \mathit{SIUP}_{br(1j)}\times P_{c(1j)}
               \bigr]
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In bot examples I assume that SIUP is one variable, so I enclose it in `\mathit{SIUM}`, which gives better spacing.

Comment: Thank for fast and right solution, with a nice elucidation mate;